# Select a post from select box and display its featured image

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a post select box and want to display featured image of the post while selecting the post from select box.Something like this 
Select the post from select box and display the featured image of that post below.

http://prntscr.com/d5e3ad
custom js file code is

```
var $ = jQuery;
$(document).ready(function(){
$("post-thumb").css("display", "none");
$("#vzxms-post-slct").on('change', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $slct_val = $("#vzxms-post-slct").val();
    console.log($slct_val);
    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: $slct_val,
        success: function(data){
            $("#post-thumb").css("display", "block");
        }
    });

});
});
```

and plugin index file with form in div wrap

```
<form method="post" action="">
            <div class="form-group-field">
                <div class="left_label"><label>
                    Select Post
                </label></div>
                <div class="rigth_input">
                    <select id="vzxms-post-slct" name="vzxms-post-slct" class="vzxms-post-slct">
                        <option selected="selected"> Select Post </option>
                        <?php
                        $args = array( 'post_type'=>'post');
                        $myposts = get_posts( $args );
                        foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
                            <option value="<?php the_ID();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></option>
                        <?php endforeach; 
                        wp_reset_postdata();?>
                    </select>
  <!-- and here i want to show image -->
                    <?php 
                    $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id), 'post'); 
                    ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo $thumb[0]; ?>" id="post-thumb"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: Yes,I have also attached a screenshot link.How can I do it on the back-end?I am working on a plugin for admin side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in select box option you can loop through all posts title like below:

```
  <select >
    <?php
    $args = array( 'post_type'=>'post');
    $myposts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
        <option value="<?php the_ID();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; 
    wp_reset_postdata();?>
    </select>
```

make an ajax call on change of select option to fetch post thumbnail from post id

```
$thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id), 'post'); 
//thumbnail link
echo $thumb[0];
```

Comment: Thanks 4 help but I have only 1 page in which working on select box and below that showing image of that post.

Comment: Make your ajax function on the same-page, or add it functions.php file and append return thumbnail link to img tag via jquery @HeroWeb512

Comment: I have updated my question with code.Please help me how can I pass the selected post id to get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id) through ajax.